# Reactjs event handler not triggered for element in a container which prevent event bubbling

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react with a map library, I use react to render elements in a container which provided by the map library.

The problem is that the container prevent event bubbling, I checkout reactjs source code found the event emitter listen on html document and depend on event bubbling to dispatch event.

How can I make the onClick handler to work? I currently addEventListener manually but don't think it a elegant way.

```
<body>
  <container preventBubbling>
    <ReactElement onClick={this.handleClick}/>
  </container>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, React depends on event bubbling instead of attaching event handlers directly to any DOM node you want events for. This is an integral part of React, and not something you can avoid without manually attaching event handlers in `componentDidMount`. And also manually removing them in `componentWillUnmount`.

What's the reason for cancelling bubbling in the map library? I'd try to remove that cancellation and see if it works.

Comment: I don't why the map library canceled bubbling but I believe situation like this exists. I'm wondering could reactjs provide an option to listen on single element instead of document?

Comment: No, React doesn't do that. You need to get a hold of the DOM node in `componentDidMount` and attach an event handler to the node directly. But that's outside of the React world, so it won't handle any cross browser differences and cleanup for you.